# How to have an alarm trigger hourly when app closed

Tags: java, android

I have a birthday app that needs to check local SharedPreferences data once a day to see if somebody's birthday is that day.

As of now, I am trying to do something supposedly simple: send a test notification every minute EVEN when I click the back button, swipe up to close the app, open another app, phone off (not shut down), etc. Plenty of other apps do this.

If I can get this about-every-minute reminder working, I can adapt it to show data from SharedPreferences, which isn't a big deal. There is one problem however:

**ALARMMANAGER simply IS NOT working the way they say it should in the docs.**

I use setInexactRepeating for my alarm manager and have that trigger a class called "ReminderAlarm", this then starts an Service that creates a notification channel and builds a test notification. The issue is that when I exit the app, no notifications will show at all. As soon as I open the app, however, they will. **So for some reason AlarmManager is not firing unless the app is open.** (I tried this with Log.d as well, it also only prints to the log if the app is open)

This is what sets the repeating alarm:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    setAlarm();
                } else {
                    cancelAlarm();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderAlarm.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 100, pendingIntent);
    }

    private void cancelAlarm() {
        //alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```

This is the alarm receiver: **(It is defined in the manifest as a receiver)**

```
public class ReminderAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderBuilderService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

This is the reminder builder service: **(It is defined in the manifest as a service)**

```
public class ReminderBuilderService extends Service {
    public final String CHANNEL_ID = "MainChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotificationChannel();
        buildNotification();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        String name = "Birthday Notifications";
        String description = "Reminds you when your friends birthday approaches";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    private void buildNotification() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent openTap = new Intent(context, EnterActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openTap, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pix_cake);
        builder.setContentTitle("TestNotification");
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("TestText"));
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A Notification should show up around every minute (I know that setInexactRepeating does not allow for exact repeated timings) but it only shows **WHEN THE APP IS OPEN**

Finally, here is the Android Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/main_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/main_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".ReminderAlarm"/>
        <activity android:name=".ListOfDaysActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".EnterActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ReminderAlarm"/>
        <service android:name=".ReminderBuilderService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @QuangNhat I edited my post to include the xml file. Sorry for not including it initially.

Comment: Use `android-studio` tag only if your question is specifically about the IDE itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager` perhaps to achieve your desired results. But what you should be using is `WorkManager` an abstraction of both depending on Android version.

`WorkManager` is highly configurable and will allow you to create a `PeriodicWorkRequest` or a `OneTimeWorkRequest` these are guaranteed to succeed. `PeriodicWorkRequest` will fire when you schedule the work, as well as when you have specified in the timer. It will execute in the background even if the app is closed or backgrounded. If you didn't want your task to execute immediately you can use a PWR(PeriodicWorkRequest) with a [FlexInterval](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%2520extends%2520androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). See the docs below for more info.

[WorkManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

[WorkManager Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[WorkmManager CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)

For example, I created two PeriodicWorkRequests that refresh services and keeps the user logged in always by renewing their token. When the user authenticates the `PeriodicWorkRequest` is created. In my case, I didn't need it to fire right away as they have just received and cached this information so I utilized the FlexInterval. When the app is backgrounded or closed, the workers continue to refresh services every 12 hours and refresh the token every 6. It works like a charm.

Here is an example:

**Build Work:**

```
 override fun beginWork() {

        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                MyWorker::class.java,
                REPEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES, // How often work should repeat
                // Flex not required.
                FLEX_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // Limits execution into a time window
                .setConstraints(
                     Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(
                                       NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
                .addTag(MY_WORKER_TAG)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                MY_UNIQUE_WORK,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                periodicLoginRequest)
```

**Worker:**

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
            // DO WORK HERE

            Result.success()
        } else {
            // HANDLE FAILURE HERE
            Result.failure()
        }
```

The above is a simple implementation, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will look into it. I have heard of work manager BUT I am unsure of what a "PWR with a FlexInterval" is

Comment: I updated and added some code above, if this helps please be sure to accept it as an answer.

Comment: This works!!! Thank you. The root of the problem turned out to be that for some reason my notifications did not properly build versus the Worker not firing.