# JobScheduler stop working sometimes on app idle

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler

I have some strange behaviour with my JobService instance. I try to detect new media on device via implementation. Most times when new media occurs,  a callback `onStartJob` fires as usual. But sometimes (not always) after long device sleep this callback never fired when new media taken (f.e on camera shot). And until the app is closed a callback is absent, but when I open the app (after new media appeared) a callback fires immediatelly. App does not do some JobScheduling logic on start (on resume and so on), but the fact of openning the app provoked my JobService implementation to shot immediatelly.

I dont think this is a "Doze" problem. Here is JobInfo instance scheduled via JobScheduler service:

```
static {
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, MediaWatcherJob.class.getName()));
    builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS));
    builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS));
    builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(
            Uri.parse("content://" + MediaStore.AUTHORITY + "/"),
            0));
    builder.setTriggerContentUpdateDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    builder.setTriggerContentMaxDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(100));
    builder.setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
    builder.setRequiresCharging(false);
    JOB_INFO = builder.build();
}
```

Here is overriden methods of `JobService`:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params)
{
    mRunningParams = params;
    // some work in separate thread with rescheduling job
    return true;
}

...

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params)
{
    // reschedule
    JobScheduler js = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    int result = js.schedule(JOB_INFO);
    return false;
}
```

**Device:**
Samsung Galaxy S8
Android 9

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @RichardDapice, Samsung Galaxy S8

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#ccn
 You may have to declare a valid/empty content provider

Comment: @ABS, interesting. you sure, content observation in that kind JobServices takes place?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, from what we can observe here there is no good answer. There can be so many factors at play that at this point they are just guesses.

Check this out: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

OEM's kill background processes, Samsung is one of the worst.

I personally have migrated all my Jobs/Background Services across all my apps to WorkManager which I have seen better results with. WorkManager is "guaranteed to complete".

Check out my post here:

[How to have an alarm trigger hourly when app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211638/how-to-have-an-alarm-trigger-hourly-when-app-closed/57212368#57212368)